# Can we query map collection using hive

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hiveql, datastax-enterprise

I have a table having map column type(text,int) in hive.I want to apply some calculation on some specific column in that map.

eg : support in table x i have map collection and i have inserted int data
id userid map (age:24,login:12)
id userid map(age:54,login:13)
.
.
Now i want count of user whose age>15  or sum of login id userwise.

Is this possible to get result in hive query and how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this queries. Lets name your map "user"

**Count users with age > 15**

```
hive> select count(*) from x where user['age'] > 15;
```

**And lets sum logins otherwise**

```
hive> select sum(user['login']) from x where user['age'] < 16;
```

If you need to cast values to **int**, use:

```
cast(user['age'] as int)
```

Comment: Thanks ,i also want join of two two tables and aggregation on columns in map.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere public?